# Can't break blocks other than sand and dirt

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

It won't let me collect any thing but sand and grass. I'm on my iPod 5 and it won't work but it works for my iPod 4.  Please help I've tried everything.

Comment: Are you using any mods or are you on a server?

Comment: Have you tried crafting tools and using those?  Oh wait, you can't even get wood.  Have you tried holding down on the block until it breaks?

Comment: Yes but I'll try wood wait one second

Answer (score 1):

You just get the stuff to make a crafting table (wood) and craft it. In the weapon area it will show you what you need to make a pickaxe so collect that, make a pickaxe and then with a pickaxe you mine that stuff that will go to your inventory.

Comment: OP doesn't know how to gather wood